# Multiprocessing API

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
num_folds = 3

def callModelScore(model, datax, datay, scoringType, folds):
    rating = model_selection.cross_val_score(gnb,
        X, y, scoring=scoringType, cv=num_folds)
    meanRating = str(round(100*rating.mean(), 2))
    print(scoringType + " " + meanRating + "%")
    return rating

from multiprocessing import Process

p1 = Process(target =  callModelScore,args =(gnb, X, y, 'accuracy', num_folds,))
p2 = Process(target =  callModelScore,args =(gnb, X, y, 'accuracy', num_folds,))
p3 = Process(target =  callModelScore,args =(gnb, X, y, 'accuracy', num_folds,))
p4 = Process(target =  callModelScore,args =(gnb, X, y, 'accuracy', num_folds,))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
p4.join()
```

---

Error:

```
BrokenPipeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-0aaad613b937> in <module>
      5 p3 = Process(target =  callModelScore,args =(gnb, X, y, 'accuracy', num_folds,))
      6 p4 = Process(target =  callModelScore,args =(gnb, X, y, 'accuracy', num_folds,))
----> 7 p1.start()
      8 p2.start()
      9 p3.start()

~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py in start(self)
    110                'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
    111         _cleanup()
--> 112         self._popen = self._Popen(self)
    113         self._sentinel = self._popen.sentinel
    114         # Avoid a refcycle if the target function holds an indirect

~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py in _Popen(process_obj)
    221     @staticmethod
    222     def _Popen(process_obj):
--> 223         return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
    224
    225 class DefaultContext(BaseContext):

~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py in _Popen(process_obj)
    320         def _Popen(process_obj):
    321             from .popen_spawn_win32 import Popen
--> 322             return Popen(process_obj)
    323
    324     class SpawnContext(BaseContext):

~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py in __init__(self, process_obj)
     87             try:
     88                 reduction.dump(prep_data, to_child)
---> 89                 reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
     90             finally:
     91                 set_spawning_popen(None)

~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py in dump(obj, file, protocol)
     58 def dump(obj, file, protocol=None):
     59     '''Replacement for pickle.dump() using ForkingPickler.'''
---> 60     ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
     61
     62 #

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I was using the python API for multiprocessing to test the API and I can't seem to get anything to work. I even tried some of the test code in the documentation for python 3. I'm using jupyter notebook with anaconda.

Comment: please add all your imports so that the code is runnable out of the box. `model_selection`, `X`, `gnb`, `y` is unknown for my interpreter

Comment: If you run the code as a script or in ipython terminal, do you get the same error? I recall previously in jupyter having to put multiprocessing code in an external file and then importing it, but I can't remember the details.

Comment: I haven't tried running it terminal. I've been sticking to notebook for all my python needs. But, that information is good to know. I'm sure for some reason it would work there and not Jupyter.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this subject, but I believe the short of it is that Jupyter Notebooks already uses pickle for data serialization. This means there is ambiguity between the data streams of the children processes and the main process that generated them. Luckily, there is a forked project of multiprocessing that seems to be actively maintained. See [multiprocess](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/) API (note, it differs by the "ing"). This API uses dill instead of pickle. Which, aside from being hilarious, should allow your shell to differentiate between the children and the main process. This is also eluded to in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Functionality within this package requires that the **main** module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.pool.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: That was a great response. Thanks!